# How to prevent start duplicit activity on dobleTap in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-activity, startactivityforresult, android-8.0-oreo

I know there is a lot of same questions BUT I didn't find solution for Android Oreo (8.0, API 26).

**What is my problem:**

When I tap more times on button that sends intent to start **activityForResult**, the activity starts MORE times!

**Strange things:**

1. Classic 'startActivity(intent)' don't do this "problem" = the activity starts only once
2. It happens only on device/emulator with Android Oreo (older versions works fine)

Example code:

**Manifest:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sandbox.jarda.cz.activityresulttest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Java code example:**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

                // starts Activity more times on double tap
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                //works fine BUT I WANT RESULT
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the view and then enable once activity is started

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
     view.setEnabled(false);   
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

     // starts Activity more times on double tap
     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

     //enable button
     view.setEnabled(true);

     //OR enable button after half second etc
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        view.setEnabled(true); 
     }, 500);

 }
```

Also you can keep disabled until you get back from other activity. Enable button in onActivityResult of MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //enable button here
}
```

Comment: Thx the delayed enabling helped. Do you know why is that necessary in new Android? :)

Comment: Yes, please read the accessibility section on https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: and probably dummy question...:D
why it was working fine with startActivity(intent);
:D

Comment: Good question, may be they have changed implementation of startActivityForResult only :D

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button once you clicked on it as below.

```
Button.setEnabled(false);
```

You can rewrite the code as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
         ((Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setEnabled(false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

                // starts Activity more times on double tap
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                //works fine BUT I WANT RESULT
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable that button for few miliseconds by using this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setEnabled(false);
            view.postDelayed(() -> view.setEnabled(true),200);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

            // starts Activity more times on double tap
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            //works fine BUT I WANT RESULT
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```